# Ember 1.13 Attrs call property change on all observers

Tags: ember.js

I have a component like:

```
App.TestCompComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    title: 'Test Component',

    disablePastChanged: function(){
        alert('disable past changed');
    }.observes('disablePast').on('init'),

    prop1Changed: function(){
        alert('Prop1 changed');
    }.observes('prop1').on('init')
});
```

and handlebars template as:

```
{{#test-comp disablePast=disablePast prop1=prop1}}
{{/test-comp}}
```

Now when a set any property/attrs on this component from parent component like  this.set('disablePast', false), both observers are fired (essentially all the attrs observers are fired).  Is that the right behavior?  As far i am concerned it should have fired just the property/attrs which changed.

[JS Bin here](http://jsbin.com/defugawexi/1/edit?html,js,output) -- Why It fires the observers on startup, those properties are not being set anywhere? 
When you click on the button and it sets only one property/attrs it fires observer twice for the properties.

What am i doing wrong here??

**Update:**

Or should we using new lifecycle hooks for components:

```
didInitAttrs
didReceiveAttrs
willRender
```

But with these hooks i dont know which property actually changed. It gives me the updated properties.

Thanks!

In case anyone is looking for a **solution**: 
http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-1-13-attrs-call-property-change-on-all-observers/8212

Comment: In case anyone is looking for a solution :

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-1-13-attrs-call-property-change-on-all-observers/8212